# Can I set a theme's logo_path programmatically?

Tags: 6, media

When adding a logo file to a custom theme, I can either

1. save my logo in the theme folder as `logo.png` (replacing the default logo.png from the theme starterkit I'm using), or
2. save my logo in the theme's images folder, using the filename I choose, and use the theme settings page at admin/appearance/settings/themename to set the logo path.

I'm looking for a way to save the logo file in the images folder, while setting the logo path programmatically. This would make sure that the logo is automatically set when enabling the theme. Wouldn't it make sense if that could be done in themename.info, using something like `settings[logo_path] = path/to/my/logo-image.png`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Drupal 6, I believe what you are looking for is

```
variable_set('logo_path', '/path');
```

At first glance though, I'm wondering why there is only one such on my site, and not one per theme.
[theme_get_settings](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_get_settings/6) appears to be grabbing defaults first, and then merging in theme specific settings on top of that.

In D7, the variable is called 'theme_themename_settings'.

Comment: I guess you mean `variable_set('logo_path', '/path')`. However looking at the variables table, there is no logo_path variable (using D7). The logo_path value is stored in a serialized array that can be retrieved with variable_get('theme_themename_settings', array()). Anyway, Suppose that you can set the value using variable_set, how would you make sure it runs when enabling a theme?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. On my site there is such a variable, but I happened to be sitting by a D6 site when I answered the question. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Reacting programmatically on theme activation however, seems like more of a challenge...

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is incorrect for Drupal 6. The variable for the logo path in 6 is the same as the one listed for 7, namely `theme_<theme name>_settings` and the logo path has the key `logo_path`, so for Garland, the logo path would be in `theme_garland_settings['logo_path']`. There is also a flag for whether the theme uses the default logo or not, which should also be set. From PHP, you can accomplish this by:

```
$new_logo="path/to/logo";
$theme_name="theme_name";
$property="theme_" . $theme_name ."_settings";
$settings = variable_get($property, array()); 
$settings['logo_path'] = $new_logo; 
$settings['default_logo'] = 0; 
variable_set($property, $settings);
```

Or from a bash script using drush:

```
new_logo="path/to/logo"
theme_name="theme_name"
property="theme_${theme_name}_settings"
drush php-eval "\$settings = variable_get('${property}', array());     
\$settings['logo_path'] = '${new_logo}'; \$settings['default_logo'] = 0; 
variable_set('${property}',\$settings);"
```

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 7, in case you need to change the logo from configs.

```
$conf['theme_my_theme_settings'] = [
  'default_logo' => 0,
  'logo_path' => 'sites/my_theme/themes/mytheme/logo.png',
  'default_favicon' => 0,
  'favicon_path' => 'sites/my_theme/themes/mytheme/favicon.ico'
];
```